# View Power BI report with filters (slicers) by link (read-only Power BI report)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I created a report in `Power BI Desktop`:
[image]

So, typical data with filters by `Region` and `City` that slice data as needed.

The report works within **Power BI Desktop** application and if I open it under my account in Power BI WorkSpace: **https://app.powerbi.com/** it works and filters too.

---

I use **share link** option in Power BI Workspace to generate a link to send the report for company workers. But when link opened by others it requires registration in Power BI and probably installation of Power BI Application.

---

How can anyone who has link from my `Power BI Workspace` see the report and use filters (slicers) also. What is the algorith for company workers to be able to see the report by link and use it in **read-only** mode without **Power BI Desktop** application?

Answer (score 1):

Best option should be to upload your report on a workspace in your company tenant.

1. Create a new workspace (if it does not exist now)
2. Add your report audience as reader / member (you can use ad group or Teams Group)
3. From power bi desktop, clic "Publish" then choose your new workspace.
4. That's it !